# Create hub instance SignalR 3

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am tring to create an instance of a Hub so that a can call a method on all of the clients. In Signalr 2 I would have used.

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub>();
```

But this seems to be missing in Signalr 3 I tried the following but I get an error.

```
IHubActivator.Create
Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported.
```

Does anybody know how this can be accomplished in SignalR 3?

I am using signalr3 rc1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve the instance using dependency injection;

```cs
public void MyController : Controller 
{
    public MyController(IHubContext<MyHub, IMyClient> context)
    {
        context.Clients.All.MyMethod("Hi there!"); // strongly typed 
    }

    // or

    public MyController(IHubContext<MyHub> context)
    {
        context.Clients.All.MyMethod("Hi there!"); // dynamic
    }
}
```

Or manually;

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) 
{
    var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<MyHub>>();
    context.Clients.All.MyMethod("Hi there!");
}
```